# Strategy pattern but with different initializer for classes

Tags: c#, design-patterns, strategy-pattern

I am currenttly working on a messenger library for emails and want to send emails in different ways.
This should be achived by initializing the needed object and then sending an email.

Because the resulting function is always the same, namely it needs a receiving E-mail address, a message text and maybe an attachment, I thought that it makes sense to use a strategy pattern in order to make the code more maintainable.

This is the interface, which will always be the same:

```
public interface IMailService
{
    void SendEMail(List<string> toEMails, string subject, string messageText);
    void SendEMail(List<string> toEMails, string subject, string messageText, List<Attachment> attachments);
}
```

The problem however is that the E-mail classes, which implement this functionality are initialized differently.

The smtp Version for example looks like this:

```
     public SmtpMailService(string server, int serverPort, bool enableSsl, string username, string password, string fromAddress)
    {
        _fromAddress = fromAddress;
        _mailClient = new SmtpClient(server);

        _mailClient = new SmtpClient(server, serverPort)
        {
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password),
            EnableSsl = enableSsl
        };
        _mailClient.Timeout = 1000000;
        
    }
```

And the exchange class is initialized this way:

```
    public void Initialize(string server, string username, string password, string domain, ExchangeVersion exchangeVersion, string fromAddress)
    {
        ExchangeService svc = new ExchangeService(exchangeVersion);
        svc.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password, domain);
        svc.Url = new Uri(string.Format("https://{0}/ews/exchange.asmx", server));

        exchangeService = svc;
    }
```

It is also planned to implement other ways to send emails using different services.

How can I create a strategy pattern out of this? Or am I having the wrong idea and is a different pattern better?

Comment: seems like you want a factory that knows how to creates the mail-services.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a strategy pattern implementation. Strategy pattern (as all patterns), when used they convey the problem they are trying to solve.

Don't mix strategy (an algorithm on how to choose something) with implementation (the way I do something).

To give an example. I want to climb some stairs.

The implementation of the `Climber` abstraction would be:

- Climb using my legs
- Climb using a bike
- Climg using my hands

The strategy would be a way to choose next step

- Climb backwards facing
- Climb skipping n steps at a time
- Climb by randomly choosing next skip steps

The `IClimbStrategy strategy` object, would be declared inside the `Climber` implementation to show the climber what's their next step.

So you don't really need a pattern (at least one from GoF) that I can see here. Maybe Factory Method could be used but your protocols have little in common to leverage there.

So go forth with just your `Abstraction` by declaring and implementing the interface and change the initialization methods so that they can be injected by using something like the [IConfiguration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.iconfiguration?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) interface from .net making your code look like this:

```
    public SmtpMailService(IConfiguration configuration)
    {   
    }

    public ExchangeMailService(IConfiguration configuration)
    {   
    }
```

Real life strategy pattern implementations example: [Database retry handling strategy in .net and](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.storage.iexecutionstrategy?view=efcore-6.0)

Comment: Excellent answer. In summary: 'Use a pattern if it describes the problem' as opposed to 'make the problem fit a pattern'.